# How to conditionally use subprocess.call("taskkill /f /im java.exe")

Tags: python, subprocess

In my python code, I need to kill any java.exe subprocess, I am using subprocess.call("taskkill /f /im java.exe"), this is working fine when java.exe subprocess exists but it failed with "ERROR: The process "java.exe" not found" if java.exe subprocess does not exist, so I want to know if there is any way to detect if any java.exe subprocess is running and then try to kill it.

Comment: This is not python specific, but OS dependant. You need to know the command to list processes (something like `ps` on linux). But is there a reason why you are not using try/except to try the kill and then continue if it fails?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `subprocess.call` to run `tasklist` or `wmic process get description` first to get a full list of running processes and see if `java.exe` is among them.